# Raspberry IP email on boot bypass

Tags: email, ports

I have configured my Raspberry Pi2 B+ to send an email through SMTPS (smtp.gmail.com:587) after the boot with the IP address of eth0 and wlan0. So Usually the eth0 will obtain an IP address by the DHCP on the internal network, but as you also know, typically you are not able to establish a connection from the internal network to the Internet using port 587. What do you suggest to trying to bypass this problem?

I know that is quite difficult to find an approach to fix this, but I would like to hear some suggestions.

Comment: this does not seem to be a security issue, but a network configuration issue. there are other SE sites for those.

Comment: Hi, please can you explain about SE sites ? Thanks

Comment: "*as you also know, typically you are not able to establish a connection from the internal network to the Internet using port 587*": I don't know this. This is just a firewall rule, so either you are administrator of the firewall and you just have to allow this outgoing connection, or you are not administrator of the firewall and are asking how to bypass your local security policy and this is no good...